# Testing element for display: none

Tags: jestjs

I'm hiding an element

```
button {
    display: none
}
```

and trying to test if it's hidden with Jest:

```
it('should not show empty button', async () => {
    const { container } = renderComponent();

    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(container.querySelector('button')).not.toBeVisible();
    });
});
```

and getting `TypeError: expect(...).not.toBeVisible is not a function`. I also tried

```
expect(container.querySelector('.ag-floating-filter-button-button')).toHaveStyle('display: none')
```

with the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Window.getComputedStyle(element)` to check its `display` style property.

```js
console.log(getComputedStyle(test).display === 'none')
```

```css
#test{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: `.getComputedStyle()` doesn't exist on `container`. Do we have access to `window` in the tests?

Comment: It's a `Window` method. Invoke it directly without a parent/prefix or write `Window.getComputedStyle()`